# Get the latest 5 objects from 2 level deep

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 3 models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date']
```

Now I need to get latest 5 items which belongs to the Category in template, so for the groups inside known category its easy

```
{% for x in category.group_set.all %}
    {{ x.name }} # get the group
    {% for y in x.item_set.all|slice:":5" %}
      {{ y.name }} # get the items from the group
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Problem is when I have list of categories and don't need groups, just latest 5 items joined which belong to the category. If I use

```
 {% for category in categories %}
     {% for x in category %} # gives me group again
```

I hope that I'm explain the problem. I'm lost all day looking for the solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem that can be easily solved with template code, because it requires a more complex queryset than those available by default. I would probably solve this problem by adding a method to the `Category` class:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    ...

    def latest_items(self):
        return Item.objects.filter(group__category=self)
```

and then in the template code:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for item in category.latest_items %} 
        {{ y.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that you might need to define the `Category` class after the `Item` class in this case, and [create the ForeignKey relationships to `Category` with strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships).

Comment: +1 The Django template language is intentionally simplistic so that you solve problems in this way instead of splattering your HTML with Python code like PHP got such a bad-rap for.

Comment: It works thanks. I'm add 'from appname.models import Item' inside your latest_items function so I don't need to change _ForeignKey_ relationship